# android - Apply same style to all API levels

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to Android and I've got a doubt that I couldn't answer searching.

I'm developing an application that would run from android v2.3 to 4.3. I know that the folders:

- values
- values-v11
- values-v14

containing the style.xml for each API level.

I want to apply the same exactly theme to all API levels. Right now, what I'm doing is copying the content of the XML to the other XML files in the other folders. But if I forgot to do that then the app looks different if the device has an android version different from the default one that I use (v2.3)

Is there a way so the app has only one style.xml file for all API levels?

Comment: if you are talking about Holo vs non-Holo you have to replace all the drawables for the views yourself to make it look holo

Comment: Just use the "values" folder without "-vXX" suffix

Comment: So, you mean if I delete the folders with "-vXX" then they would all use the style.xml from "values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles.xml located in the res/values directory is used by all versions, so use this one.